# How to customize PHPMailer error messages

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer in my website to send emails to users when they create an account, and I want it to echo error messages back to the user. Is there a way I can customize the error messages it returns (on error)? (basically what shows up as the value of `$mail->ErrorInfo`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to some extent by creating your own language file, then asking PHPMailer to use it:

```
$mail->setLanguage('xx', '/path/to/languagefiles/');
```

These params are then used to construct a path to the file according to a fixed pattern:

```
$lang_file = $lang_path . 'phpmailer.lang-' . $langcode . '.php';
```

So you would need to create your translation file in:

```
/path/to/languagefiles/phpmailer.lang-xx.php
```

Note that the `en` language code is treated specially as the English language strings are built-in to the PHPMailer class, and not kept in an external file, so to create an arbitrary custom language, use a placeholder language code as I've done here with `xx`.

See the files in the `language` folder for the format and expected values of the language files. It's along these lines:

```php
$PHPMAILER_LANG['authenticate']         = 'Erreur SMTP : échec de l\'authentification.';
$PHPMAILER_LANG['connect_host']         = 'Erreur SMTP : impossible de se connecter au serveur SMTP.';
$PHPMAILER_LANG['data_not_accepted']    = 'Erreur SMTP : données incorrectes.';
```

You only need to define the strings that you want to override, as they are overlaid on top of the default English translations.

You can also inject a debug handler and use that to process error messages for you – see the `Debugoutput` property in the source code for examples.

Comment: which one is the English language? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: There isn't a separate English translation file because it's built-in to the PHPMailer class.

Comment: I've revised my answer as it was quite wrong in a few places!